# Having a the same file with different content in git repository

Tags: git, csv, heroku, github

I would love to have an empty csv file in my local git repo but when when I push it to my remote repo hosted on heroku. It would be used to collect user information and will now contain some contents that is not in the local git repo.
But whenever I perform a git push it changes the file to an empty csv file even if I did not stage the file. I have also tried using .gitignore but I found out that after removing the cached file it just removes the file from the remote repo but not in my local repo which is not what I want. Please is there a way to achieve this using git or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a tracked file without adding/committing and pushing any local modification, you can consider using [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit):

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged-- yourFile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is really no good way (or need) to achieve this in a natural or elegant fashion. Remove the file from the repository, add it to. `.gitignore` and make your application so that it behaves like "file size = 0" if they file does not exist. I.e., make sure your application can create the file if  necessary.

Sure,  git being git, you could probably hack something together, but it will be much more complicated and brittle.